# NUnit & MOQ: Testing a try catch that calls another method when an Exception is caught

Tags: nunit, moq

I understand that the MOQ framework wasn't really designed to help in this instance, but perhaps you might be able to help...

I have a method that uses a try/catch that calls a notification method whenever an exception is thrown. What I am trying to do is create an integration/unit test that checks to make sure SendNotification is called when any exception is thrown.

Method Under Test:

```
public virtual void MonitorIntradayBuilds(IIntradayBuilds intradayBuilds)
{
    try
    {
        var intradayBuildFound = intradayBuilds.CheckForIntradayBuilds();
        if (intradayBuildFound && !IntradayBuildsComplete && !DailyBuildsFound)
        {
            IntradayBuildsComplete = intradayBuilds.StartIntradayBuilds();
            //should start daily builds?
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        SendNotification("MonitorIntradayBuilds threw an exception", ex);
    }
}
```

Test Case:

```
    [Test]
    public void it_should_notify_developers_immediately_if_there_is_a_problem_when_checking_for_intraday_builds()
    {
        //Arrange
        var mockDua = new Mock<DUA>();
        var mockIB = new Mock<IIntradayBuilds>();

        //Act
        mockIB.Setup(x => x.CheckForIntradayBuilds()).Throws(new Exception());
        mockDua.Object.MonitorIntradayBuilds(mockIB.Object);

        //Assert
        mockDua.Verify(x => x.SendNotification(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<Exception>()), Times.Once);
    }
```

I keep hitting a Moq.MockException and then see that SendNotification "expected an invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times..."

I've tried using the [ExpectedException] attribute on the test case, but to no avail. It makes the test pass, but still doesn't call the SendNotification method.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it.

Turns out you need to set the CallBase property on the System Under Test that you are mocking up.

Test case is now:

```
    [Test]
    public void it_should_notify_developers_immediately_if_there_is_a_problem_when_checking_for_intraday_builds()
    {
        //Arrange
        var mockDua = new Mock<DUA>();
        var mockIB = new Mock<IIntradayBuilds>();
        mockDua.CallBase = true; // <<<< Added this line!

        //Act
        mockIB.Setup(x => x.CheckForIntradayBuilds()).Throws(new Exception());
        mockDua.Object.MonitorIntradayBuilds(mockIB.Object);

        //Assert
        mockDua.Verify(x => x.SendNotification(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<Exception>()), Times.Once);
    }
```

Hopefully someone else finds it helpful :)